Is there a straightforward way in fetching a text file into an SQL server in Kotlin (Android Studio)?
I am a total beginner in Kotlin and there's really something I want to do. Pass on by writing a string variable into a text file and sending it to my phpmyadmin databases or maybe, even just put it in the file manager of my cpanel.
Is there a straightforward code and way of doing it instead of using Xampp and Postman?
Thanks!

we know nothing about your backend and what file or data you want to save. for rest apis you can use retrofit. pretty simple to use.
